# Customize ListRowPresenter to include inline view below horizontal list

Tags: android, leanback

I am trying to customize ListRowPresenter where it should have a horizontal grid view with a detailed view of the selected item below it. I want to inject another Presenter to the ListRowPresenter.

I extended ListRowPresenter and the horizontal grid is displayed fine but the detailed view is not getting added to it.

Comment: you need to show your images, just text so hard for help